# Issues with tooltip

Tags: html, css

I've built a modal where in the header, there's a tooltip explaining certain points to a user of the modal for clarity.

The problem I am running into is that the tooltip isn't behaving properly. The tooltip text is over lapping the modal instead of hovering above it when your cursor passes over it.

Edit* Preview of my first attempt on https://jsfiddle.net/rjfz47na/

Feature Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<style>
    .woocommerce-MyAccount-content:not(.content-edit-account) {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
}
.woocommerce-account {
    clear: both;
}

a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a {
    color: #2ea3f2;
}

h4 {
    font-family: "DIN Next Slab Pro Bold", serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #1b1b1b;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #333;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.woocommerce-account .ps-courses__image img {
    height: auto;
    width: 20px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>

<style>
    body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #F1EEF1;
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  align-items: center;
  /*       background: #F1EEF1;
  border: 1px solid #D2D1D4;
  */      display: flex;
  height: 365px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 700px;
}
.email {
  background: #DEDBDF;
  border-radius: 16px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: width 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1),
    height 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1),
    box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1),
    border-radius 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}
.email:not(.expand) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.email:not(.expand):hover {
  background: #C2C0C2;
}
.from {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 200ms 100ms cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}
.from-contents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}
.to {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 100ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1);
}
.to-contents {
  transform: scale(.55);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}
.avatar {
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: -11px;
  width: 85px;
}
.name {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 32px;
  width: 180px;
}
.top {
  background: #2c5424;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 70px;
  transition: height 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  width: 700px;
}
.avatar-large {
  border-radius: 21px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: 26px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.name-large {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.x-touch {
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 50px;
}
.x {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
}
.x-touch:hover .x {
  background: #E1D9D1;
}
.line1 {
  background: #2C5424;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(9px) translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
  width: 2px;
}
.line2 {
  background: #2C5424;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(9px) translateY(4px) rotate(-45deg);
  width: 2px;
}
.bottom {
  background: #FFF;
  color:  #444247;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 295px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 700px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.row {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 85px;
}
.twitter {
  margin-left: 16px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 30px;
}
.medium {
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
}
.link {
  margin-left: 16px;
}
.link a {
  color:  #444247;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.link a:hover {
  color:  #777579;
}
.email.expand {
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.10), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
  height: 365px;
  width: 700px;
}
.expand .from {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 100ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1);
}
.expand .from-contents {
  transform: scale(1.91);
}
.expand .to {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms 100ms cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}
.expand .to-contents {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.p2{
    padding: 0 12px;
}

/* button div */
#buttons {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* start da css for da buttons */
.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translate(0px, 5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 5px);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
}

.green {
  background-color: #15B358;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #218838;
}

.green:hover {
  background-color: #28a745;
}

.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #CE3323;
}

.red:hover {
  background-color: #dc3545;
}

.black {
  background-color: #343a40;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #23272b;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px 12px;
}

.black:hover {
  background-color: #23272b;
}




    input {
        border: none;
        width: 170px;
        height: 25px;
        outline: none;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .tooltip {
    position: relative;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #2c5424;
    animation: shake 500ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

.tooltip:before,
.tooltip:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.tooltip:before {
    border-width: 10px 8px 0 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
    top: -15px;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}

.tooltip:after {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    background: #2c5424;
    width: 350px;
    height: 95px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    top: -130px;
    left: -10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}

.tooltip:hover::before,
.tooltip:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}

@keyframes shake {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(2deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(-3deg);
    }
    70% {
        transform: rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="email expand" onclick="this.classList.add(&#39;expand&#39;)">
      <div class="from">
        <div class="from-contents">
          
          <div class="name">Assign Backup Cards</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="to">
        <div class="to-contents">
          <div class="top">
            <div class="avatar-large"><strong>HEADS UP!</strong></div>
            <div class="name-large"><b>
                You have <span id="card-count-total">3</span> unassigned Backup Cards.
              </b>

                <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="This feature will allow you to assign your available pool of unassigned safety cards to either your course or courses you have purchased and sent out to other individuals. Once assigned, the cards will be mailed out when the course is completed.">?</span>


            </div>
            <div class="x-touch" onclick="document.querySelector(&#39;.email&#39;).classList.remove(&#39;expand&#39;);event.stopPropagation();">
              <div class="x">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="bottom">

            <div class="row">
                <div style="display: flex">
                    <div style="flex-shrink: 1;">
                        <div class="ps-courses__image">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 26px; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 0; display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content 2fr 1fr; grid-auto-flow: column; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <div> Test! Online Course </div>
                            <div> Voucher: HYH65-GF3C8 </div>
                            <div> Email: s***6@yahoo.com </div>
                            <a onclick="bcr_addCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn green">Add Card</a>
                            <a onclick="bcr_removeCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn red">Remove Card</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="card-count" data-voucher="JN3SU-GF3C8">0</span> Cards
                        </div>
                        <div><b>This is your course </b></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>

            
            <div class="row">
                <div style="display: flex">
                    <div style="flex-shrink: 1;">
                        <div class="ps-courses__image">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 26px; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 0; display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content 2fr 1fr; grid-auto-flow: column; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <div> Test! Online Course </div>
                            <div> Voucher: HYH65-GF3C8 </div>
                            <div> Email: s***6@yahoo.com </div>
                            <a onclick="bcr_addCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn green">Add Card</a>
                            <a onclick="bcr_removeCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn red">Remove Card</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="card-count" data-voucher="JN3SU-GF3C8">0</span> Cards
                        </div>
                        <div><b>This is your course </b></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div style="display: flex">
                    <div style="flex-shrink: 1;">
                        <div class="ps-courses__image">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 26px; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 0; display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content 2fr 1fr; grid-auto-flow: column; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <div> Test! Online Course </div>
                            <div> Voucher: HYH65-GF3C8 </div>
                            <div> Email: s***6@yahoo.com </div>
                            <a onclick="bcr_addCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn green">Add Card</a>
                            <a onclick="bcr_removeCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn red">Remove Card</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="card-count" data-voucher="JN3SU-GF3C8">0</span> Cards
                        </div>
                        <div><b>This is your course </b></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            

            <div class="row">
                <div style="display: flex">
                    <div style="flex-shrink: 1;">
                        <div class="ps-courses__image">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 26px; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 0; display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content 2fr 1fr; grid-auto-flow: column; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <div style="
    padding-left: 0px;
"> Test! Online Course </div>
                            <div> Voucher: HYH65-GF3C8 </div>
                            <div> Email: s***6@yahoo.com </div>
                            <a onclick="bcr_addCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn green">Add Card</a>
                            <a onclick="bcr_removeCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn red">Remove Card</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="card-count" data-voucher="JN3SU-GF3C8">0</span> Cards
                        </div>
                        <div><b>This is your course </b></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>

            <div class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
              <a href="#" class="btn black">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </div>




      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        
  

</body></html>
```

Edit*: I'm trying to have the tooltip behave like what is seen in https://jsfiddle.net/dnu297g1/3/ while keeping the same position for the tooltip as my original attempt. Having it Beside the header of the modal on the right side.

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="This feature will allow you to assign your available pool of unassigned safety cards to either your course or courses you have purchased and sent out to other individuals. Once assigned, the cards will be mailed out when the course is completed.">?</span>
    </div>
    </form>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #424B54;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

input {
  border: none;
  width: 170px;
  height: 25px;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  background: #2c5424;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
}

.tooltip:before,
.tooltip:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.tooltip:before {
  border-width: 10px 8px 0 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
  top: -15px;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.tooltip:after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  background: #2c5424;
  width: 350px;
  height: 95px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  top: -130px;
  left: -10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.tooltip:hover::before,
.tooltip:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}
```

Comment: Can you post here a working example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet of what you want to achieve.
I had to do some modifications on the CSS code of your `tooltip` class.

Moreover, I added a `div` tag with an `id="anim"` that surrounds your `span` tag such as in the jsfiddle you attached in your post.

What the `<div id="anim">` does is to trigger the `shake` HTML5 animation which does a slight rotation whenever you hover over your tooltip `span` tag.

Hope that can help you.

```
@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```css
.woocommerce-MyAccount-content:not(.content-edit-account) {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
}

.woocommerce-account {
  clear: both;
}

a,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  color: #2ea3f2;
}

h4 {
  font-family: "DIN Next Slab Pro Bold", serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.woocommerce-account .ps-courses__image img {
  height: auto;
  width: 20px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {
    align-items: center;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 125vh;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 700px;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 730px;
    top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.email {
  background: #DEDBDF;
  border-radius: 16px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: width 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1), height 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1), box-shadow 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1), border-radius 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.email:not(.expand) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.email:not(.expand):hover {
  background: #C2C0C2;
}

.from {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 200ms 100ms cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.from-contents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.to {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 100ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1);
}

.to-contents {
  transform: scale(.55);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.avatar {
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: -11px;
  width: 85px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 32px;
  width: 180px;
}

.top {
    background: #2c5424;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    transition: height 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    width: 740px;
}

.avatar-large {
    border-radius: 21px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.name-large {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 35px;
}

.x-touch {
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.x {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
}

.x-touch:hover .x {
  background: #E1D9D1;
}

.line1 {
  background: #2C5424;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(9px) translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
  width: 2px;
}

.line2 {
  background: #2C5424;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(9px) translateY(4px) rotate(-45deg);
  width: 2px;
}

.bottom {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #444247;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 730px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.row {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 85px;
}

.twitter {
  margin-left: 16px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 30px;
}

.medium {
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
}

.link {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.link a {
  color: #444247;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link a:hover {
  color: #777579;
}

.email.expand {
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0 6px 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 730px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.expand .from {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 100ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1);
}

.expand .from-contents {
  transform: scale(1.91);
}

.expand .to {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms 100ms cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.expand .to-contents {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.p2 {
  padding: 0 12px;
}


/* button div */

#buttons {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* start da css for da buttons */

.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translate(0px, 5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 5px);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
}

.green {
  background-color: #15B358;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #218838;
}

.green:hover {
  background-color: #28a745;
}

.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #CE3323;
}

.red:hover {
  background-color: #dc3545;
}

.black {
  background-color: #343a40;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #23272b;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px 12px;
}

.black:hover {
  background-color: #23272b;
}

input {
  border: none;
  width: 170px;
  height: 25px;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    background: #2c5424;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 17px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 35px;
}


.tooltip:before, .tooltip:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


.tooltip:before {
    border-width: 10px 8px 0 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #15B358 transparent transparent transparent;
    top: 40px;
    transform: translateY(40px);
    line-height: 12px;
    position: absolute;
}

.tooltip:after {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    background: #2c5424;
    width: 250px;
    height: 95px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
    top: 45px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: translateY(20px);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000000;
    display: block;
}

.tooltip:hover::before,
.tooltip:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

#anim:hover {
  animation: shake 500ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="email expand" onclick="this.classList.add(&#39;expand&#39;)">
      <div class="from">
        <div class="from-contents">
          
          <div class="name">Assign Backup Cards</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="to">
        <div class="to-contents">
          <div class="top">
            <div class="avatar-large"><strong>HEADS UP!</strong></div>
            <div class="name-large"><b>
                You have <span id="card-count-total">3</span> unassigned Backup Cards.
              </b>
            </div>
                    <div id="anim">
                 <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="This feature will allow you to assign your available pool of unassigned safety cards to either your course or courses you have purchased and sent out to other individuals. Once assigned, the cards will be mailed out when the course is completed.">?</span>
              </div>
            <div class="x-touch" onclick="document.querySelector(&#39;.email&#39;).classList.remove(&#39;expand&#39;);event.stopPropagation();">
              <div class="x">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="bottom">

            <div class="row">
                <div style="display: flex">
                    <div style="flex-shrink: 1;">
                        <div class="ps-courses__image">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 26px; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 0; display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content 2fr 1fr; grid-auto-flow: column; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <div> Test! Online Course </div>
                            <div> Voucher: HYH65-GF3C8 </div>
                            <div> Email: s***6@yahoo.com </div>
                            <a onclick="bcr_addCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn green">Add Card</a>
                            <a onclick="bcr_removeCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn red">Remove Card</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="card-count" data-voucher="JN3SU-GF3C8">0</span> Cards
                        </div>
                        <div><b>This is your course </b></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>

            
            <div class="row">
                <div style="display: flex">
                    <div style="flex-shrink: 1;">
                        <div class="ps-courses__image">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 26px; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 0; display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content 2fr 1fr; grid-auto-flow: column; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <div> Test! Online Course </div>
                            <div> Voucher: HYH65-GF3C8 </div>
                            <div> Email: s***6@yahoo.com </div>
                            <a onclick="bcr_addCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn green">Add Card</a>
                            <a onclick="bcr_removeCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn red">Remove Card</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="card-count" data-voucher="JN3SU-GF3C8">0</span> Cards
                        </div>
                        <div><b>This is your course </b></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div style="display: flex">
                    <div style="flex-shrink: 1;">
                        <div class="ps-courses__image">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 26px; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 0; display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content 2fr 1fr; grid-auto-flow: column; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <div> Test! Online Course </div>
                            <div> Voucher: HYH65-GF3C8 </div>
                            <div> Email: s***6@yahoo.com </div>
                            <a onclick="bcr_addCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn green">Add Card</a>
                            <a onclick="bcr_removeCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn red">Remove Card</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="card-count" data-voucher="JN3SU-GF3C8">0</span> Cards
                        </div>
                        <div><b>This is your course </b></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            

            <div class="row">
                <div style="display: flex">
                    <div style="flex-shrink: 1;">
                        <div class="ps-courses__image">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 26px; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 0; display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content 2fr 1fr; grid-auto-flow: column; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <div style="
    padding-left: 0px;
"> Test! Online Course </div>
                            <div> Voucher: HYH65-GF3C8 </div>
                            <div> Email: s***6@yahoo.com </div>
                            <a onclick="bcr_addCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn green">Add Card</a>
                            <a onclick="bcr_removeCard(&#39;JN3SU-GF3C8&#39;)" class="btn red">Remove Card</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="card-count" data-voucher="JN3SU-GF3C8">0</span> Cards
                        </div>
                        <div><b>This is your course </b></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>

            <div class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
              <a href="#" class="btn black">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </div>




      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        
  

</body></html>
```

Comment: So its it finally restricting the texts within the borders so thank you for that. However, the tooltips moved to the middle of the screen rather than be after the period in "You have 3 unassigned Backupcards." . @orissin

Comment: What I'm looking to have is the tooltip be side the last character of the header like in my original post however the tooltip shows outside the modal when hovered over so that it can be read. @oris sin

Comment: In your original post you didn't post any snippet. Just the HTML code and a fiddle independent of what you had in your example. Try to be a bit more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, my apologies. In my initial post, I provided the html/css code of my attempt and provided the fiddle link for a preview of what it looks like and how it was currently behaving.

I listed that "The tooltip text is over lapping the modal instead of hovering above it when your cursor passes over it. " . I attached the html code for how I'd like the tooltip to behave while still being in the same position as my initial attempt.

For my future reference, could you highlight where I could've been more clear? I'd like to not make the same mistake again. @oris sin

Comment: Actually, I am sorry, I have seen your editted post now. My bad. I thought you already posted your code but I just checked that you editted it 34 minutes ago. I was checking the last piece of HTML you posted just with the `form` and the `span` tag.

Comment: Check my editted post now. I did some minor tweaks on the html and css. It is not collapsing with the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251412/discussion-between-oris-sin-and-atfirstyoutry).